# How to get unique records from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

How can I get unique records from database by linq?

For example:
I have something like that

```
07.12.2016
07.12.2016
08.12.2016
08.12.2016
10.12.2016
```

I would like to have something like that

```
07.12.2016
08.12.2016
10.12.2016
```

My query:

```
var query2 = (from availableDate in bazaDC.seanses
                        where availableDate.id_filmu == id
                        orderby availableDate.data ascending
                        select availableDate.data).Distinct();
availableDate.DataSource = query2;
availableDate.DataBind();
```

And html:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="dostepneDaty" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="repertuar_szczegoly.aspx?id=<%# Eval("id_filmu") %>&&data=<%# Eval("data","{0:dd.MM.yyyy}") %>"><%# Eval("data","{0:dd.MM.yyyy}") %></a><br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Distinct() doesnt work.

And Im going to include table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[seanse] (
    [id_seansu] INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [godzina]   TIME (7) NOT NULL,
    [data]      DATE     NOT NULL,
    [id_filmu]  INT      NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id_seansu] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_seanse_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([id_filmu]) REFERENCES [dbo].[filmy] ([id_filmu])
);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `GroupBy()` appropriate? [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.110).aspx), [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)

Comment: Easiest way would be using GroupBy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this piece of code

```
 var query2 = (from availableDate in bazaDC.seanses
                     where availableDate.id_filmu == id
                     group availableDate by new { availableDate.id_filmu, availableDate.data } into g
                     orderby availableDate.data ascending
                     select new { g.Key.id_filmu, g.Key.data});
```

You're adding the group by clause so it will retrieve unique values

Comment: Everything fine but I have to get id_filmu aswell bucause Im using that in repeater ID="dostepneDaty", you know...

So from query2 I have to get two fields, id_filmu and data.

Comment: oh ok, then you will need to group by date and id_filmu, check the updated answer in a few seconds

Comment: How can I do it with two field to groupby? What is the syntax?

Comment: Not working, many errors.
I think, I cant do it like that:
      select g.key.id_filmu, g.key.data

I mean I cant have 2 fields in select.

Comment: Yep, I got it. Ur code is correct but in select I had to add something like that:

 select new {g.Key.id_filmu, g.Key.data })

Cheers guys.

Comment: You're right!! I added the missing piece to the answer

Answer (score 4):

From what I know your select distinct should work, but you can always do the same thing by grouping and selecting the first element.

Examples Below:

Select Distinct:

```
 var query2 = bazaDC.seanses
             .Where(availableDate => availableDate.id_filmu == id)
             .Select(x => x.data)
             .Distinct()
```

Group By:

```
 var query2 = bazaDC.seanses
             .Where(availableDate => availableDate.id_filmu == id)
             .GroupBy(x => x.data )
             .Select(g => g.First())
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a [dotnetfiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dTiIsv) showing it working as expected.  Below is the LINQ statement used in that example.

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> dataSource = (from availableDate in seanses
    where availableDate.id_filmu == 1
    orderby availableDate.data
    select availableDate.data).Distinct();
```